# Zend Framework 2: No base path provided

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Using Zend Framework 2 with Apigility and I get this error when running the command:

> php public/index.php development enable

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No base path provided' in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Helper/BasePath.php:38
```

Comment: Is this a clean install of the apigility skeleton?
Or have you added bootstrapped code to the application?

Comment: @Erik Apigility Skeleton

Answer (score 0):

There is some changes in new version.
See https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-development-mode for correct call to enable dev mode.